# PHP get next id in database

Tags: php, database

I need PHP next `id`, ex: I have these `id`'s in the database: 10, 11, 15, 19, 31,32,34 .....

```php
$img_id=$_GET[img_id]; // to get image id from browser  
$row['id']; // to get id from database
```

How can I use PHP `$i++` and check if `id` is set in database? And ignore empty `id`.

Because I want to put next image bottom. While some images were deleted!

Comment: your question is still unclear. what does it mean "i want to put next image bottom"? if you want to insert another row into table, just insert it and qutoincrement will set id automatically

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand of your question, you have rows in your database which ids are not consecutive (1, 3, 13, 16, etc), and you wish to access those rows by searching with consecutive numbers from a loop as possible ids?

```
for($i=0; $i<100; $i++)
{
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` = ' . $i;
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
        echo 'This id exists in the table: ' . $id . '<br />';
    }
}
```

100 here acts as a potential number, but it should achieve what you need.
There's a ton of solutions that you can apply to your problem, but that would be the most straight forward I think of with the question you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

It's quite unclear what you are trying to say. But I will give it a shot.

I think what you mean is you have deleted some records from the table and it does not continue from last `MAX(id)` in the next insert. For that you could try:

**As @col mentioned below, never use this in production, just your testing environment. Once a record is deleted sequence is lost.**

```
mysql_query("ALTER TABLE `table_name` AUTO_INCREMENT = 1");
```

What this does is that if you have a table named `images` with the maximum `id` of say `99` and you deleted this image. Next image you enter will have the `id=100`. So ids will now look something like `97,98,100`. This will force MySQL to continue from `MAX(id) + 1`, so it looks `97,98,99`.

Also a  handy function to get the last insert id from php:

```
$last_id = mysql_insert_id();
```

Now `$last_id` will have the last `AUTO_INCREMENT` value from database.

Hope this helps.

Comment: **never** touch autoincrement field, dude

Comment: sounded like he wanted that. maybe I shouldn't assume a lot. edited the answer.

Comment: well, while being noobs, we all wanted strange and harmful things. But in fact, if you c come with idea of changing autoincremrnt field, you either shouldn't do that or you just don't need autoincrement

Comment: personally i have used it couple of times, after a large delete. maybe its the OCD in me.

Comment: so, you spoiled your data couple of times

Comment: not spoiled per se, more like cleaning up a table used for logging.

Comment: that's second case I mentioned above - logging table do not require autoincrement field at all